# When is an operator called a 'field operator'?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, operators, terminology, field-theory, definition

I am slightly confused of the conditions under which a general operator $\hat A$ is called a 'field operator'. It was originally my conception that the condition would be that $\hat A$ either creates or destroys a particle at a given spatial location. But [this Phys.SE question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/146835/) suggests in the general case this is not true. My question is therefore:

**When is a general operator $\hat A$ called a field operator?**

(a source would be helpful)

Comment: I'm not sure "field operator" is actually a codified term, but I'd suggest it simply denotes an operator-valued function (or distribution) on space(time) instead of a single operator.

Comment: @ACuriousMind In this case dose the operator: $$\hat \psi(x)=\int \frac{d^3p}{(2\pi)^{3/2}(2E_p)^{1/2}}(\hat a_p e^{-ip\cdot x}+\hat b_p^\dagger e^{ipx})$$ (and its complex conjugate) have a name other then field operator?

Comment: That seems to be a (free) complex scalar field.

Comment: @ACuriousMind Ok thanks. So this would be the 'field operator associated with a free complex scalar field' or something along those lines?